# I can't get my SharePoint ListItem Fields

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, com, web-parts

I want to show all fields of a certain ListItem. This includes LookUpFields and ChoiceFields. But I only seem to be able to show Textfields, like Title. How can I show all fields of my ListItem?
The problem is that I get an error when I try to show other fields of a listitem the way I got 'Title' to show, as if the strings I type in don't exist as fields in that listitem. But they do exist and are populated with values!
What is good way to show custom fields of a listitem without getting ObjectReference errors?
Also I get this error: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

```
    private void foo()
    {
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ApplicationContext.Current.Url))
        {
            _list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList").Title);
            _items = _list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
            context.Load(_items);
            context.ExecuteQueryAsync(
                new ClientRequestSucceededEventHandler(OnListItemsRequestSucceeded),
                new ClientRequestFailedEventHandler(OnListItemsRequestFailed));
        }
    }
private void OnListItemsRequestSucceeded(Object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
    {
        // this is not called on the UI thread
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(ShowListItemDetails);
    }
public void ShowListItemDetails()
    {
foreach (ListItem i in _items)
        {
TextBox_Details.Text += i["Title"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
// Now the rest of the fields of this item.
        }
}
```

Edit: What also is a big problem is I cant get the debugger working. This code is running as a Silverlight webpart on a local Sharepoint site. I attach the debugger to the iexplorer.exe but it won't break.
If I could get the debugger to work it would be a great help indeed.

Comment: And the problem is actually *what*? What gets wrong when you dump more fields? What issues you experience when dealing with non-Text fields?

Comment: What Ondrej probably means is that you should give us the error you are getting when dealing with non-text fields. Also: Set a breakpoint in your foreach ListItem loop and you can access all fields (just to see they are there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have  tell the query what all fields you need to pull from lists

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = itemPosition;
            camlQuery.ViewXml =
                @"<View>
                    <ViewFields>
                      <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                      <FieldRef Name='Category'/>
                      <FieldRef Name='Estimate'/>
                    </ViewFields>
                    <RowLimit>10</RowLimit>
                  </View>";
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

for more details

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx#SP2010ClientOM_Accessing_Large_Lists

Comment: I have seen this example but haven't tried it yet. Is it mandatory to provide a CamlQuery for these custom fields? I was under the impression CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery() would give me every field of a ListItem.

Comment: not exactly their are some other ways available as well but my motive was to tell to name all columns you need

Comment: I have tried your approach. I get'null' when I try to use the fieldname provided in the query. TextBox_Details.Text += i.FieldValues["Production"]; ... Result is a null exception

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/11/01/using-the-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-part-3.aspx try this article

Comment: on how to debug you have to just press f5 on your VS2010 http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=174

Comment: After a long depressing day I amazingly got the debugger working, I can see the ListItem fields now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get item properties you will need to specify all the item properties you need in the second parameter of the ClientContext.Load method

e.g

```
        string server = "http://localhost";
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(server);
       Web web = context.Web;
        var spList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyTitle");
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        var items = spList.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(items, 
            itema => itema.Include(
                item => item,
                item => item["ComplexProperty"]));
        context.ExecuteQuery();`
```